# Windows command line how to call a tool for every file in directory tree

Tags: windows, command-line

I have many directories with many files. How to call a command (echo i.e.) for every file?

What I have done is:

```
for %a in (*) do D:\wget>xidel.exe --extract  "//a/@href" %a > D/wget/links.txt
```

It can do it's job in single directory. But how to force it to process all directory tree recursively?

Comment: If you want people here to help you, it's generally best not to make rude remarks Like "just help instead of writing unhelpful comments".  Being rude to people you're asking to provide you with their time for free help solving your problems is generally a very poor way to get them to want to help you. :-) It's also better to write full, clear questions about the problem you're trying to solve, instead of "How to call for every file?" with no other information. Please [edit] your post to provide more details about what you're asking.

Comment: You are right - just get a bit angry when some "people here" gives me totally misspointed advices, just becouse they don't have an idea how to solve problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `/R` switch to the `FOR` command.

> FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
>       statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
>       specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
>       assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
>       will just enumerate the directory tree.

So to echo every filename starting in `E:\Temp` and recursing subfolders, you can use

```
cd /d E:\Temp
for /R %a in (*) do echo %a
```

Comment: Thanks, win cmd is definitely not my favorite tool.